# same variable inside regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use same variables in regexp pattern.

```
string Pattern = "<li.*?class=\".*?item\".*?>.*?<a.*?href=\"(?<link>.*?)\">(?<a1>.*?)>(?<title>.*?)(a1)";
```

e.g if there is `"<span>"` in a1 ,after the title variable the `"<span>"`should become.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reference a previously captured group

Use

```
\index//where index is the group number
```

**OR**

```
\k<name>//where name is the name of the group
```

So in your case it should be `\k<a1>`

---

Also regex is not used for parsing HTML

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: \k<a1> k unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @alikoyuncu use it with `@"\k<name>"`..`@` denotes a verbatim string which treat escape characters as literals..this happens cuz \ before any character is treated as a special character..so you need to escape that check with `@`